# How to filter separate parameter in url rewrite in PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have two url's for my wesite.

**First**
`localhost/job/2/Employment-News`

**Second**
`localhost/job/Latest-Admission/50571/UP-ITI-Admission-2016-Fourth-Round-Apply-Online-`

I want to get separate parameters.

I have tried this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) category.php?Id=$1&category=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) post_details.php?postid=$1&post=$2&mycat=3 [L]
```

Comment: Please give an example result URL.

Comment: _"I have tried"_ needs to be followed by an example of the expected result and and explanation of the current result. You basically need to explain your actual _issue_.

Comment: It might be easier and even more performant to rewrite any request to a target `router.php/original/path/from/request`, then read the extra path from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and process it in PHP.

Comment: please tell me how to filter multiple parameter in php url rewriting

Comment: There are no parameters in your request URIs, only virtual directories. You are trying to rewrite directories into GET parameters. Thus if you decide to implement the approach of rewriting the request path to a fixed script reading the PATH_INFO, you would split that on slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^job/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?Id=$1&category=$2
RewriteRule ^job/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ post_details.php?mycat=$1&postid=$2&post=$3 [L]
```